# Arranging the columns in Spark dataframe by Iterating through the column value

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Not sure if this question has been asked already but I could not find the solution so I am posting the question.
I have a spark data frame which has the below input value:

```
 +----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                        market_Year           |       Quarter-Range                 |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]                     |    null
|/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]                     |    [0D-6M]                          |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]                     |    [0D-6M],[6M-18M]                 |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]                     |    [18M-2Y]                         |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]                     |    [18M-2Y]                         |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]                     |    [18M-2Y]                         |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]                     |    [18M-2Y]                         |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]                     |    [6M-18M]                         |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

I am looking for the output which should be:

```
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                        market_Year           |                Quarter-Range        |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]                     |  [0D-6M],[6M-18M]                   |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]                     |  [18M-2Y]                           |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]                     |  [18M-2Y]                           |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]                     |                                     |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

If anyone can help me to achieve this output without using UDF will be a great help.

Thanks in advance

```
Dataset<Row>   DF_to = printdf.withColumn("Quarter-Range", explode(array("Quarter-Range))).groupBy(col(market_Year))
                .agg(collect_set("Quarter-Range").distinct();
```

I am getting this output:

```
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                        market_Year           |          Quarter-Range              |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]                     |[[0D-6M],[6M-18M], [0D-6M], [6M-18M]]|
|/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]                     |                           [[18M-2Y]]|
|/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]                     |                           [[18M-2Y]]|
|/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]                     |                                   []|
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is the type of `Quarter-Range`? String, array of struct, something else? Can you for instance provide the result of `printSchema()`?

Comment: The type is String.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your example is correct

Your sample solution has few small typos, but when i adjusted it and executed, the output was not the same as output pasted by you

In your output you have record for Y3 but it does not exist in input-data. It is also not produced by your example after adjustments.

If i understand it correctly, in your input you have strings and collect_set is not returning what you expect. I think that inside your explode you should use split instead of array

Here is my example in Scala (core logic in Java will look similar):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val inputData = Seq(
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]", ""),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[0D-6M]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[0D-6M],[6M-18M]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[6M-18M]")
)

val df = inputData.toDF("market_Year", "Quarter-Range")
val aggregatedDf = df
  .withColumn("Quarter-Range", explode(split(col("Quarter-Range"), ",")))
  .groupBy("market_Year")
  .agg(
    collect_set("Quarter-Range")
      .as("Quarter-Range")
  )

aggregatedDf
  .withColumn("Quarter-Range", concat_ws(",", col("Quarter-Range")))
  .show(truncate = false)
```

The ouput is:

```
+-------------------------+----------------+
|market_Year              |Quarter-Range   |
+-------------------------+----------------+
|/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]|                |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]|[0D-6M],[6M-18M]|
|/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]|[18M-2Y]        |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]|[18M-2Y]        |
+-------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Hello @M_S, Thanks for your help. I have added the right set of input which is being passed in the data-frame. It was the Typo and I missed the "3Y".
I have gone through your comment and I appreciate your help. One thing I just wanted to ask, why this extra set of "[ ]" are appearing while doing the explode and split? Tough I have used Explode_outer to keep the null value but it is not working as per the expected output (where the test case is not expecting any extra [ ]). Could you please help on this ?

Comment: Its returning [] because it is array with one element which is empty. You can swap it manually to null (check my updated answer) if this is ok for you. If you want to have empty space on .show(), then i think that you need convert array to string and handle it during conversion

Comment: Hi.. agreed I need to cast to string but my doubt was with extra pair of "[ ]", appearing in every row. The expected results  are having only a valid pair of brackets e.g.[0D-6M],[6M-18M]  but this code is returning "[[0D-6M], [6M-18M]]".

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification, now i think i understand it. Please check my updated answer. Now i used concat_ws to transform array into string, you dont have extra brackets and empty column is handled as in your expected answer

Answer (score 0):

i have make dataframe as string of all columns.

```
val inputData = Seq(
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]", ""),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[0D-6M]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[0D-6M],[6M-18M]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[6M-18M]")
)

val df = inputData.toDF("market_Year", "Quarter-Range")
```

First to Flatten data and just process the data on second line

```
val dfx = df.withColumn("Quarter-Range",explode(split($"Quarter-Range",",")))
val dfg = dfx.groupBy("market_Year").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_set(when($"Quarter-Range".isNotNull, $"Quarter-Range"))).as("Quarter-Range"))
```

Output look like

```
+-------------------------+----------------+
|market_Year              |Quarter-Range   |
+-------------------------+----------------+
|/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]|[0D-6M],[6M-18M]|
|/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]|[18M-2Y]        |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]|[18M-2Y]        |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]|null            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
```