# Sorting the dataframe by Iterating through the column value

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark Scala, and I am facing an issue while writing the logic for a column.
Below is my Input data:

```
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                        Policy_Year           |       Quarter                       |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|/market/policy[DIV|2004Y]                     |    null                 |            
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]                     |    [0D-6M]                          |
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]                     |    [0D-6M]                          |
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]                     |    [18M-2Y]                         |
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]                     |    [18M-2Y]                         |
|/market/policy[DIV|2003Y]                     |    [18M-2Y]                         |
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]                     |    [6M-18M]                         |
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]                     |    [6M-18M]                         |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

And I wanted the value in the below format, viz is the column value "Quarter" should be sorted based on range:

```
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                       Policy_Year            |                Quarter              |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]                     |   [0D-6M],[6M-18M]                  |
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]                     |   [6M-18M],[18M-2Y]                 |          
|/market/policy[DIV|2003Y]                     |   [18M-2Y]                          |
|/market/policy[DIV|2004Y]                     |                                     |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

I was referring to one link : and got the answer which is similar, but it did not help with respect to sorting [arranging-the-columns-in-spark-dataframe-by-iterating-through-the-column-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127430/arranging-the-columns-in-spark-dataframe-by-iterating-through-the-column-value)

`df.withColumn("Policy_Year", explode_outer(split(col(POLICY_YEAR),","))).groupBy(col(Quarter))                 .agg(collect_set("Policy_Year").as("Policy_Year"))`

Output I am getting :

```
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                        Policy_Year           |                Quarter              |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]                     |   [[0D-6M], [6M-18M]]               |
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]                     |   [[18M-2Y], [6M-18M]]              |          
|/market/policy[DIV|2003Y]                     |   [18M-2Y]                          |
|/market/policy[DIV|2004Y]                     |   []                                |
+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Value for Row#2 is not proper.

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S : I have modified the data from the link mentioned above, since my requirement is almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

I first created the data set with columns of type `String`:

```
val inputData = Seq(
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]", ""),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[0D-6M]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[0D-6M],[6M-18M]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]", "[18M-2Y]"),
  ("/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]", "[6M-18M]")
)

val df = inputData.toDF("market_Year", "Quarter-Range")
```

The first expression is used to flatten the data, the second one is used to process it:

```
val dfx = df.withColumn("Quarter-Range",explode(split($"Quarter-Range",",")))
val dfg = dfx.groupBy("market_Year").agg(concat_ws(",", collect_set(when($"Quarter-Range".isNotNull, $"Quarter-Range"))).as("Quarter-Range"))
```

Output looks like below:

```
+-------------------------+----------------+
|market_Year              |Quarter-Range   |
+-------------------------+----------------+
|/equity/dividends[DIV|1Y]|[0D-6M],[6M-18M]|
|/equity/dividends[DIV|2Y]|[18M-2Y]        |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|3Y]|[18M-2Y]        |
|/equity/dividends[DIV|4Y]|null            |
+-------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort but the expected out put has a range e.g: 

|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]                     |   [0D-6M],[6M-18M] 
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]                     |   [6M-18M],[18M-2Y]

Please see my expected output data mentioned above.

Comment: i had taken different context of data in the year column and row too.so this is universal code for your problem too.try this code,will be work fine.

Comment: Hi, Tried the solution provided by you.. its not sorting. In the second row the data is appearing like [18M-2Y],[6M-18M] I want this to be sorted i.e. ,[6M-18M],[18M-2Y]

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
val w=Window
      .partitionBy("Policy_Year")
      .orderBy("asNumber")
      .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing);

df.withColumn("asNumber", regexp_extract(col("Quarter").substr(0,3),"(\\d{1,2})",1).cast("int"))
  .select(col("Policy_Year"), array_distinct(collect_list("Quarter").over(w)).as("Quarter"))
  .groupBy("Policy_Year")
  .agg(first("Quarter").as("Quarter"))
  .show(false)
```

Input:

```
+-------------------------+--------+
|Policy_Year              |Quarter |
+-------------------------+--------+
|/market/policy[DIV|2004Y]|null    |
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]|[0D-6M] |
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]|[0D-6M] |
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]|[18M-2Y]|
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]|[18M-2Y]|
|/market/policy[DIV|2003Y]|[18M-2Y]|
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]|[6M-18M]|
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]|[6M-18M]|
+-------------------------+--------+
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------+--------------------+
|Policy_Year              |Quarter             |
+-------------------------+--------------------+
|/market/policy[DIV|2001Y]|[[0D-6M], [6M-18M]] |
|/market/policy[DIV|2002Y]|[[6M-18M], [18M-2Y]]|
|/market/policy[DIV|2003Y]|[[18M-2Y]]          |
|/market/policy[DIV|2004Y]|[]                  |
+-------------------------+--------------------+
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: hi, the Regex is working fine when I have the small set of input for my test data, but its taking time lot of time when the data volume is high. Can i request you to provide answer twithought Regex or UDF?

Comment: Also this would work for a particular column but if the same logic I have to apply more than one column, wouldn't be a generic. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @Mohit UDF should be avoided unless inevitable, as it's implementation is not known to catalyst optimiser. For multiple colums, can you elaborate? I think the only thing that would change would be the regex to extract number that can determine order